# Django read a csv file in unix which is created in mac/windows system

Tags: python, django, unix, csv

I am trying to read a CSV file in django. Sample file is located [here.](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/juhstin/Glacier-Grotto/master/DB/data/MemberList.csv)

```
if request.POST:
    try:
        fl = request.FILES['csv']
        reader = csv.DictReader(fl, "rU")
        all_keys = reader.fieldnames
        reader.next()
      // if this does not work then provide dialect as well. 
    except Exception as e:
        try:
            reader = csv.DictReader(fl, "rU", dialect=csv.excel)
            all_keys = reader.fieldnames
            reader.next()
        except Exception as e:
            return render(request, "error.html", {"errr":str(e.message)})
```

Both the times, I get the following error -

```
Error: 'new-line character seen in unquoted field - do you need to open the file in universal-newline mode?'
```

Files generated in unix systems work well.

Any clue how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

you can try reopening the fd with the correct mode:

```
os.fdopen(fl, 'rU')
```

also I don't think the call to [`reader = csv.DictReader(fl, "rU", dialect=csv.excel)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html?highlight=dictreader#csv.DictReader) is what you expect, the second parameter is field names,

Answer (score 0):

I would try either:

```
reader = csv.reader(f1, dialect=csv.excel_tab)
```

or open the file in `universal newline mode` and pass it to `reader`.

```
reader = csv.reader(open(self.file, 'rU'), dialect=csv.excel_tab)
```